# Связь моделей Django

Tags: python, django

Для изучения Django (1.8) решил сделать свою имиджборду. Но не могу понять, как связать 2 модели (оставил только необходимые поля, связь через id):

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    …
    openpost = models.OneToOneField(Post, null=True, blank=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    …
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True)
```

Каждому треду соответствуют много постов, связь `ForeignKey`. И к каждому треду надо указать открывающий пост `openpost`. При реализации как указано выше при выполнении появляется ошибка

> NameError: name 'Post' is not defined

Пути решения вижу 2: как-то исправлять эту ошибку или внести `openpost` в `Post` и пользоваться обратной связью. Какое решение более архитектурно красивое и верное? И если первое, то как исправить ошибку? Второе мне не нравится потому что вроде как каждому посту есть оп-пост, но не каждый пост открывающий, так что внесение `openpost` в `Post` кажется не очень логичным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
…
    openpost = models.OneToOneField("Post", null=True, blank=True)


class Post(models.Model):
…
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: помогло, но тогда получается коллизия имен (поле `thread` в `Post` и имя обратной связи для `openpost`). Проблему решил переназвав обратную связь: `openpost = models.OneToOneField("Post", null=True, blank=True, related_name='opens_post')`. Добавьте в ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Flowneee, так а такое зачем вам делать? Что бы join меньше делать?

Comment: что конкретно? не очень понял

Comment: @Flowneee Ну в одном месте Foreign Key, а в другом месте вы делаете One To One?

Comment: Просто мне важно только какой у треда оп-пост, обратная связь мне вообще не нужна вроде как, поэтому я вынес ее в `Thread`. Потому я и спросил, нормально ли так делать связи. Мне показалось так логичнее, хотя может и неправильно так делать.

Comment: Ну вообще говоря в Foreign Key можно указать related_name, но при запросе это будет дополнительный join. Для ускорения запросов, возможно и подойдёт.